# Apex Trigger for Creating a New Account Record when Custom Field on Custom Object is UpDated

Tags: apex, trigger, sales-cloud

G'afternoon, I have spent the last week trying to write this code in my Dev Sandbox and keep getting random errors. This is my first attempt at writing an Apex Trigger so I apologize if it seems somewhat elementary as far as the issues I am having. Either way  I am very grateful!

Unfortunately I can't even get it to save without continuously giving me errors(which keeps preventing it from saving)... can someone please advise?

The current error I am getting is

> Error= Line10 "Method does not exist or incorect signature:
>   [SOBject:Account_Reques__c].RecordTypeId(String)

```
trigger newAccountRequestConvert on Account_Request__c (after update)
{
   if(trigger.isUpdate){
        List<Account> NewAccountInserted = new List<Account>();
        for(Account_Request__c acc : trigger.new)
        {
             if(Account_Request__c.Account_Request_Status__c=='Convert' &&  Account_Request__c.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c=='Advertiser')
            {
                Account converted = newAccount (
                                acc.RecordTypeId('012000000000jv1') = Account_Request__c.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c,
                            acc.Name                                                =Account_Request__c.Account_Name__c,
                                acc.Website                         =Account_Request__c.Website__c,
                                acc.Contact_Email__c                        =Account_Request__c.Company_Email__c,
                                acc.Phone                           =Account_Request__c.Phone__c,
                                acc.BillingStreet                   =Account_Request__c.Billing_Street__c,
                    acc.BillingCity                     =Account_Request__c.Billing_City__c,
                    acc.BillingState                            =Account_Request__c.Billing_State__c,
                    acc.BillingPostalCode               =Account_Request__c.Billing_Zip__c,
                    acc.BillingCountry                              =Account_Request__c.Billing_Country__c
                                    );
            }

         if(Account_Request__c.Account_Request_Status__c=='Convert' && Account_Request__c.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c=='Agency')
        {
            Account converted = new Account(
                acc.RecordTypeId=('012000000000jv2')    =Account_Request__c.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c,
                        acc.Name                                                =Account_Request__c.Account_Name__c,
                            acc.Website                         =Account_Request__c.Website__c,
                            acc.Contact_Email__c                        =Account_Request__c.Company_Email__c,
                            acc.Phone                           =Account_Request__c.Phone__c,
                            acc.BillingStreet                   =Account_Request__c.Billing_Street__c,
                acc.BillingCity                     =Account_Request__c.Billing_City__c,
                acc.BillingState                            =Account_Request__c.Billing_State__c,
                acc.BillingPostalCode               =Account_Request__c.Billing_Zip__c,
                acc.BillingCountry                              =Account_Request__c.Billing_Country__c
                                );             
             }
           }
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect a trigger  to insert `Account` objects when specific changes are made to a custom `Account_Request__c` object to look something like this:

```
trigger newAccountRequestConvert on Account_Request__c (after update) {
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    for (Account_Request__c ar : Trigger.new) {
        if (ar.Account_Request_Status__c == 'Convert') {
            Boolean advertiser = ar.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c == 'Advertiser';
            Boolean agency = ar.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c == 'Agency';
            if (advertiser || agency) {
                Id rtId = advertiser ? '012000000000jv1' : '012000000000jv2';
                Account converted = new Account(
                        RecordTypeId = rtId,
                        Name = ar.Account_Name__c,
                        Website = ar.Website__c,
                        Contact_Email__c = ar.Company_Email__c,
                        Phone = ar.Phone__c,
                        BillingStreet = ar.Billing_Street__c,
                        BillingCity = ar.Billing_City__c,
                        BillingState = ar.Billing_State__c,
                        BillingPostalCode = ar.Billing_Zip__c,
                        BillingCountry = ar.Billing_Country__c
                        );
                accounts.add(converted);
            }
        }
    }
    insert accounts;
}
```

Your code has many examples of references to what are SObjectField tokens rather than fields of a particular SObject e.g. `Account_Request__c.Account_Request_Status__c`.

It is not entirely clear what your record type logic is trying to do; I've assumed that its a different Account record type depending on whether its an advertiser or agency request.

I suggest that before you go much further with writing triggers you invest the time in working through the [Apex Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.pdf) that provides examples of many of the core techniques you'll need. It will save you time in the long run.

Comment: Thank you, I input that code and it gave me the following error:
expecting a semi-colon, found '}' on line 22, I entered a ';' at the end of line 21
and then got the following error:
Variable does not exist: RecordTypeId
Not sure if it helps but those 2 numbers are the Id #'s I get when I click on each one from the Account Record Type Pages. The name of the Account Record Types are " "Advertiser_Account_Record " and " Agency_Account ".

Comment: @DonaldBohrisch Yes I missed a semi colon and I had `newAccount` rather than `new Account`. Try with both those changes.

Comment: You Rock.... it came across with NO errors finally :)
Now to test it and get back to you on the effectiveness of it... THANK YOU :D

Comment: Finally tested it and just wanted to say Thank You again!

Comment: @DonaldBohrisch You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 acc.RecordTypeId=('012000000000jv2') =Account_Request__c.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c,
```

to

```
 acc.RecordTypeId='012000000000jv2', 
 // Not sure what this line is doing    
 //Account_Request__c.Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c,
```

if your trying to dynamically set the record type based on "Is_this_an_Agency_or_Advertiser__c" you will need to look up the related record types and use an if statement to populate the correct record type id value.

Also you shouldn't be hardcoding recordId but retrieving them based on name..

Comment: Trying to define between 2 Record Types the info going to be inserted into. Trigger is taking a Record from our Custom Object 'Account Request' thats submitted by a user for our review and allowing us to UpDate the Record to 'Convert' in our 'Account Request Status' field. The 'Is this an Agency or Advertiser' is the field in our Custom Object that determines the Account Record Type the info will go to, ie 'Advertiser' or 'Agency'.
Tried to utilize the ID# because I couldn't figure out how to simply call out the Account Record Type by name, ie 'Agency Account' and 'Advertiser Account Record'.